# Is a static IP address permitted on the Amazon Elastic Cloud Computing (EC2) service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, static-ip-address

We are planning to have an application run on Amazon's cloud which requires a static IP address for it to work. However it appears from Amazon's documentation that static IP addresses are **not** allowed.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#features  -->     Elastic IP Addresses

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=65389

> Allen / Posted: Aug 3, 2007 7:30 AM PDT in response to: Steve Isaacson ...
>
> The machine's external IP address is
> essentially a static address. You
> will have it until your instance is
> terminated or until Amazon needs to
> renumber its network. This could be
> months or years from now, which in
> this day and age, is about as static
> as it gets.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-06-26/TechnicalFAQ.html#d0e7741

> 8.12.    Can I use a static IP address in my instances?
>
> No. Your image must be
> configured as a DHCP client and it
> will be assigned an IP address.

This however confused me a little bit:
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1346 --> Introduction

> Elastic IP addresses are static IP
> addresses designed for dynamic cloud
> computing. An Elastic IP address is
> associated with your account, not a
> particular instance, and you control
> that address until you choose to
> explicitly release it. Unlike
> traditional static IP addresses,
> however, Elastic IP addresses allow
> you to mask instance or availability
> zone failures by programmatically
> remapping your public IP addresses to
> any instance associated with your
> account. Rather than waiting on a data
> technician to reconfigure or replace
> your host, or waiting for DNS to
> propagate to all of your customers,
> Amazon EC2 enables you to engineer
> around problems with your instance or
> software by programmatically remapping
> your Elastic IP address to a
> replacement instance.

Is there a way that a machine instance can have a static IP address linked to it?

Answer (score 8):

In AWS-EC2 Console you can associate a Elastic IP. This is a static IP that is dedicated for you. When the Elastic IP is not associate to a instance you pay for it.

> No cost for Elastic IP addresses while in use
>
> $0.01 per non-attached Elastic IP address per complete hour
>
> $0.00 per Elastic IP address remap – first 100 remaps / month
>
> $0.10 per Elastic IP address remap – additional remap / month over 100

This IP you can assign to your running EC2 instance.

See setup dialog:
[image]

Comment: Hi amra - would this be a formal "static IP" like what is required for an SSL cert for instance?

Comment: (That's not what I need btw, but just trying to understand what this "static ip" could be used for)

Answer (score 4):

Elastic IP is the right thing to do for static IP. Whereas individual instances are configured via DHCP, and could technically be assigned a new IP address, your elastic IP never changes.

The elastic IP address is effectively a second address that you can assign to your instance alongside the one assigned via DHCP. One useful feature of elastic IP is that you can reassign it to a different instance transparently: if one of your instances fails, you can reassign the elastic IP address to a replacement instance with a single command.

Comment: As I understand it, the application itself needs to be on a system that has a static-ip. I dont think an elastic ip would work...

Comment: Can you explain more? Elastic IP gives you the guarantee that address a.b.c.d will always route to your instance. Does your application need a stronger guarantee than that? (Does it inspect the hardware, for instance?)

Comment: Hi - the application documentation says that the minimum requirements are a static IP. It does not say why or what for... I'm emailing the tech support of the company to inquire more - whether its actually needed...

Comment: Without knowing why one is required, it's hard to say whether elastic IP will be sufficiently static. Maybe you could try it and see what breaks? :)

Answer (score 1):

**To more clarify:**

An EIP (Elastic IP) address is nothing more than a reserved address which is assigned to your EC2 account, and which you can allocate to any running VM you own. Since it is an inert object - when not assigned to a VM it does nothing but cost you a tiny amount of money, and, when assigned, its' cost drops to zero and the VM switches its' default address out and assumes the EIP instead.

```
Cost Elastic IP: 
$0.00 for one Elastic IP address associated with a running instance 
      * $0.005 per additional Elastic IP address associated with a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis 
      * $0.005 per Elastic IP address not associated with a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis 
      * $0.00 per Elastic IP address remap for the first 100 remaps per month 
      * $0.10 per Elastic IP address remap for additional remaps over 100 per month
```

For Amazon EC2 instance, will not able to use EIP to run multiple instances simultaneously with same IP.